# Xamarin Emulator funciona,mas após atualizar pro VS 2017 o aplicativo é copilado mas aparece como em branco

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Eu uso o xamarin android player para fazer as simulações e testar meus apps
mas depois que eu atualizei pro Visual Studio 2017 o emulador funciona parcialmente,eu faço o design no `main.AXML` e o `build & deploy` funciona normalmente,porem no emulador o app aparece como em branco.

**Segue o screenshot**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já deixei 15 minutos assim só pra ter certeza de que não fosse algum problema de processamento porem nada(ja havia acontecido antes no VS2015 que as vezes demorava uns 3 segundos pro app mostrar suas funcionalidades mas agora nem isso quer mais)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema Resolvido

Em `Properties` > `Build`

Ativei as opções: 
`Allow Unsafe Code` e `Optimize Code`

e Após outro `Build & Deploy` o app Funcionou como deveria
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]